# YouTube video streaming for Cardboard (Unity)

Tags: android, video, unity-game-engine, youtube, google-cardboard

I want to put YouTube streaming video inside the app for Cardboard (for Android and iOS). I know the are plugins to do similar things such as "Easy Movie Texture" but they don't support YouTube streaming. I've found "Youtube Video Player" inside Unity Asset Store but I'm not entirely sure that it will work with CardboardMain.prefab (I mean properly splitting 360 video for two screens).
Please help with this issue.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using Easy Movie texture with Youtube Video Player you can get the just pass the result of Youtube Video Player to Easy Movie Texture video path, and will works like a charm :)